# How to retrieve different positions of an element within an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to retrieve an array containing the (not only the first) positions of an element within an array. For instance in the following array:

```
["blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red"]
```

I would like to retrieve `[0, 2, 3]` when I pass `"blue"` as a parameter. Supposedly, if the element is nowhere in the array, the function should return `nil`.

Comment: "[I]f the element is nowhere in the array, the function should return `nil`"-- This is a bad design. Keep things simple; do not try to make exceptions.

Comment: When you give an example you should assign all input values to variables (e.g. `colors = ['blue',...]`), so that readers can reference those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method definition:

```
def diff_pos arr, key
  result = arr.each_with_index.map { |el,i| i if el == key }.compact
  result.empty? ? nil : result
end
```

Execution:

```
x = ["blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red"]
diff_pos(x, "blue")
# => [0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: That does not give the desired result.

Comment: @sawa thanks, forgot about the "return nil if not found" condition. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
result = ["blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red"]
.to_enum.with_index.select{|e, _| e == "blue"}.map(&:last)
result = nil if result.empty?
result # => [0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red"]
result = a.map.with_index{|e,i| i if e == "blue"}.compact
=>[0,2,3]
result = nil if result.empty?
```

Comment: @sawa it is rails method, I should use `empty?` method  in ruby, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2):

```
def offsets(arr, target)
  off = arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i]==target }
  off.empty? ? nil : off
end

colors = %w| blue red blue blue red |

offsets(colors, "blue")
  #=> [0,2,3]
offsets(colors, "chartreuse")
  #=> nil
```

One could alternatively write:

```
def offsets(arr, target)
  arr.index(target) && arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i]==target }
end
```